# "E212: Can't open file for writing" when saving in gvim on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

I opened a new file with `:e ~\mypath\myfile.txt` using gvim on Windows.

But when I try to save my file using `:w` I get this error message:

> E212: Cannot open file for writing

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

gvim could obviously not create diretories for me, so it worked after I had created the `mypath\` directory in my home directory.